# In app purchase in Android application, and test with sandbox account

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I want to implement in app purchase in my app in android. Can anybody
help me for best example for this,  and how can I test with sandbox
account?

Answer (score 5):

As of today (or yesterday) Google has allowed "sandbox" testing for in app purchases. Please check out info
[here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html?rd=1#test-purchases) and
[here](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html?rd=1#billing-testing-test)

[image: Google Announcemnet]

Comment: use "android.test.purchased".

Answer (score 1):

you can use test purchase package for testing inapp provided by google. use this product id for testing  "com.test.purchased" it redirects you to test inapp product id .

Comment: Its not "com.test.purchased". It is "android.test.purchased". This is mentioned here : 'http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html#billing-testing-static'

Comment: this doesnot work for in-app subscriptions, any idea how to test subscriptions?

Comment: Rat-a-tat-a-tat Ratatouille: did you get any idea how to test subscription?

Answer (score 0):

> You can read this

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html

> For test your app you must publish this app on google play, There is
>   no sandbox for in app purchase for android

Comment: there is no need to publish the app developer has to just upload apk and make it as draft application but developer has to publish product ids to test app from test account. This step is required to generate application specific public key.

Comment: Draft Apps are No Longer Supported https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html?rd=1#draft_apps

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing#prepare

You can check this link for test purchases

There are three reserved product IDs for testing static Google Play Billing responses:

**android.test.purchased**
When you make an Google Play Billing request with this product ID, Google Play responds as though you successfully purchased an item. The response includes a JSON string, which contains fake purchase information (for example, a fake order ID).